# Why the function unexpected is not called?

Tags: c++, exception, terminate, c++builder-6

I expect the following code to invoke my *unexpected* handler, but my *terminate* handler is called instead:

```
#include <except>
#include <iostream>

void my_terminate() {
    std::cerr << "my terminate handler";
    std::exit(0);
}

void my_unexpected() {
    std::cerr << "my unexpected handler";
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::set_terminate(my_terminate);
    std::set_unexpected(my_unexpected);
    try {
        throw std::exception();
    } catch (const std::logic_error&) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The [C++ Builder 6 Developer's Guide](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31668) explicitly encourages installing custom unexpected handlers via `set_unexpected()`. **What am I doing wrong, or is this simply a bug in C++-Builder 6?**

Comment: what happens if you remove `catch (const std::logic_error&)`?

Comment: @stijn you mean the whole try-catch thing? The same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The handler set by the call to `std::set_unexpected` (for [`std::unexpected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected)) will be called when an unexpected exception is thrown; not when an exception is unhandled. The unexpected handler is called when **a dynamic exception specification is violated**.

By way of example;

```
void my_terminate() {
    std::cerr << "my terminate handler";
    std::exit(0);
}

void my_unexpected() {
    std::cerr << "my unexpected handler";
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void function() throw() // no exception in this example, but it could be another spec
{
    throw std::exception();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::set_terminate(my_terminate);
    std::set_unexpected(my_unexpected);
    try {
        function();
    } catch (const std::logic_error&) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

> my unexpected handler

The handler set by `std::set_terminate` is called by [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) (for numerous reasons as listed in the reference). Of interest here is that the default behaviour when an **exception is thrown but not caught is to call `std::terminate`**.

Comment: Does this mean unexpected does only address exception specifications?

Comment: @Wolf, I believe so, yes. It is called when a dynamic exception specification has been violated. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected

Comment: @Wolf: Yes. An "expected" exception is one that matches the exception specification of the function it's leaving. An "unexpected" exception is one that doesn't. In your example the exception is *unhandled* but not *unexpected*.

Comment: Is there a specific way to detect uncaught exceptions or is `terminate()` only called in fatal situations?

Comment: @Wolf, I think `terminate` is pretty [much it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate). It is called if an exception is not caught. I'm not sure on the situation, but `catch(...)` catches all the exceptions...?

Comment: @Wolf, +1 nice question by the way. I think it is often not understood how these functions interact and how the handlers can be customised.

Comment: Yes, I recently (unexpectedly) stumbled upon `abort` in production code, and now I try to understand what makes a program "waterproof".

Answer (score 4):

When uncaught exception is occur, **`terminate`** is called.

```
int main()
{
    throw 1; // terminate
}
```

When unexpected exception is occur, **`unexpected`** is called.

```
void foo() throw(int)
{
    throw "unexpected will be called.";
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

I'll show you example program which occur terminate/unexpected:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

#define TEST_TERMINATE

void my_terminate()
{
    std::cout << "terminate!" << std::endl;
    std::abort();
}
void my_unexpected()
{
    std::cout << "unexpected!" << std::endl;
    std::abort();
}

void foo() throw(int)
{
    throw "unexpected will be called.";
}

int main()
{
    std::set_terminate(my_terminate);
    std::set_unexpected(my_unexpected);

#ifdef TEST_TERMINATE
    throw 1;
#else
    foo();
#endif
}
```

(live example for [terminate](http://ideone.com/oynChl), [unexpected](http://ideone.com/9zhejv))

Comment: +1 This also answers my next question which I added as a comment to [the first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25403651/2932052).

Comment: ...but is `terminate` called for this only reason?

Comment: @Wolf According to `http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate`, there's **10** cases to call `terminate`.